# Help with AP Macroeconomics FRQ

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

I am a senior in High school and am taking an AP Macroeconomics course. I just took an FRQ and received an F on it. I asked my teacher multiple times to explain why my answers were wrong, but to no avail, I did not receive any answers. I would love to have some feedback on what I got wrong and possible ways to improve for my next FRQ. I have attached the questions and my responses below. The scoring for the FRQ is as follows: 3,1,2,2,2. Thank you to anyone that can help me out!

[image: FRQ Questions]
[image: My responses:][image: My Responses-2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Your initial point looks correct (GDP above full-employment GDP). But there was no reason to shift the SRAS or AD curves.

B. Sounds OK.

C. Looks OK to me, maybe the labels were the issue.

D. The explanation sounds OK but you mention "As seen in the graph" - does that mean the graph in part A? Maybe that's the issue, perhaps you needed a different graph for this one.

E. Sounds OK.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help!